# AngularDart: Component attribute

Tags: angularjs, dart, components, angular-dart

I'm new to Angular and I have the following problem.

I'm trying to create a component that can be `active`. I currently set it up so it detects if an attribute called `active` exists and sets its internal state accordingly.

```
<page active page-id="page-1"></page>
```

The problem emerged when I wanted to remove the active state. How should I go about it? Should I switch to css classes? Or maybe use a directive?

Comment: how about simply remove the attribute? Setting the attribute as TRUE/FALSE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a little 'hacky' but, first you need to get the element somehow and access the attribute Map directly and just remove it like,

HTML

```
<page active page-id="page-1" id="page_one"></page>
```

Dart

```
querySelector('#page_one').attributes.remove("active");
```

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Element#id_attributes

Comment: Doesn't this go against the mindset of Angular? Perhaps there is a way more in spirit with the framework?

If that's the only way, I suppose I'm better off using classes then.

Comment: Sure you would wrap it in a directive, but ultimately you would still be doing it this way. By calling the attributes Map directly and removing it.

Comment: I don't get it? whats wrong with modifying the elements attribute this way. It exactly how a directive would do it.

Comment: You can use `active="true"`/`active="false"` and bind the value to a property `active="{{isActive}}"` (can't remember if there is any support for boolean attributes in Angular. Polymer has `active?="{{isActive"}}"` which adds/removes the attribute depending on the value of `isActive`.